# Conditioning of the eigenvector matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ diagonalizable non-symmetric matrix. Let

$$A = U \Lambda U^{-1}$$

What (if any) is the relationship between the condition number of eigenvector matrix $U$ and $A$ ?

Comment: An arbitrarily ill-conditioned normal matrix will always have ideally well-conditioned eigenvectors.

Comment: Fair point, can something be said in the case where $A$ is diagonalizable and not-normal.